# Positive existential theory of an extension of the ring

Tags: logic, model-theory, computability, formal-languages

When we know that the positive existential theory of a ring $R[x]$ in a language $L$ is undecidable, does it follow that the positive existential theory of $R[x,y]$ in the same language $L$ is also undecidable?

Or can it be that the positive existential theory of $R[x,y]$ is decidable in $L$ ?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

I am looking at the specific case $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x, e^{\mu x} \mid \mu \in \mathbb{C}]$ and the language $L=\{+, \cdot , \frac{d}{dx}, 0, 1, x\}$.

The positive existential theory of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ in $L$ is undecidable.

Does it follow that the positive existential theory of $\mathbb{C}[x, e^{\mu x} \mid \mu \in \mathbb{C}]$ in $L$ is undecidable, since $\mathbb{C}[x] \subset \mathbb{C}[x, e^{\mu x} \mid \mu \in \mathbb{C}]$ ?

Or do we have to reduce the positive existential theory of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ into the positive existential theory of $\mathbb{C}[x, e^{\mu x} \mid \mu \in \mathbb{C}]$ ?

Comment: Can you explain what "positive existential theory" means? The top 7 google hits for that phrase are your own questions here and on MO, so it doesn't seem to be a standard technical term ...

Comment: A positive existential theory of a structure $S$ is the set of the positive existential sentences that are true in $S$. A positive existential sentence is  a positive existential formula without quantifier-free variable $$\exists x_1 \dots x_n \phi (x_1, \dots , x_n)$$ **Positive** existential formula means that the formula $\phi$ has no negation. @HenningMakholm

Comment: Are $R[x]$ and $R[x,y]$ specifically _polynomial_ rings? Is $L$ just the language $\{0,1,{+},{-},{\times}\}$, or can/will it include constants for particular ring elements too?

Comment: I am looking at the specific case $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x, e^{\mu x} \mid \mu \in \mathbb{C}]$ and the language $L=\{+, \cdot , \frac{d}{dx} , 0, 1, x\}$. @HenningMakholm

Comment: This is a great question! In general, knowing that $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ tells you nothing about the relative complexities of the theories (positive existential or otherwise) of the structures - for instance, if $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ then $Th_{pe}(\mathcal{A})\subseteq Th_{pe}(\mathcal{B})$ ("$Th_{pe}$" denotes the positive existential theory), but just because one set is larger than another tells you nothing about their relative complexity. For example, the ring of integers is contained in the ring of reals, but the latter's theory is decidable and the former's isn't.

Comment: We have that the positive existential theory of the smaller ring is undecidable. Can it be that the positive existential theory of the bigger ring in the same language is decidable? $$$$ So we have to apply a reduction to proof the undecudability, right? @NoahSchweber

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, it can also go the other way - the smaller one can be undecidable and the larger can be decidable. It's a good exercise to come up with an example of that. In the special case you mention, I don't know whether there is anything we can say - it's possible that your specific situation, where the structures are the rings of polynomials in one and two variables respectively over some field, is special and lets us say something, but I doubt it. You would have to do some work - it would suffice to exhibit such a reduction.

Comment: Do we have to reduce the positive existential theory of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ into the  theory of $\mathbb{C}[x, e^{\mu x} \mid \mu \in \mathbb{C}]$ ? $$$$ I have shown the undecidability of the positive existential theory of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , \frac{d}{dx} , 0, 1, x\}$ by reducing the structure $(\mathbb{N}; +, \cdot , 0, 1)$ into that theory. Should I maybe reduce $(\mathbb{N}; +, \cdot , 0, 1)$ also into the  theory of $\mathbb{C}[x, e^{\mu x}]$ to show the undecidability? @NoahSchweber

Comment: If you can prove such a reduction, that would suffice (although technically it's not the only way to prove undecidability).

Comment: So both reductions that I proposed in my previous comment are OK, right? @NoahSchweber $$$$ What other ways are there?

Comment: If you reduce a set $A$ to a set $B$, and $A$ is undecidable, then $B$ is undecidable. But you have to actually *prove* such a reduction. In this case, it's not clear to me how to do so (or even if the claimed statement is true!).

Comment: If we use the first reduction that I proposed we have to express $\mathbb{C}[x]$ by a positive existential formula in the structure $(\mathbb{C}[x, e^{\mu x}];+,\cdot ,\frac{d}{dx},0,1)$ right? @NoahSchweber

Comment: And when we use the second reduction we have to express $\mathbb{N}$ by a positive existential formula in the structure $(\mathbb{C}[x, e^{\mu x}]; +,\cdot ,\frac{d}{dx},0,1)$. We can achieve it by the formula $$n \in \mathbb{N} \leftrightarrow \exists x \left (n \in \mathbb{C} \land tx'=nx \land x(1)=1\right )$$ right? (I used this formula to prove that the theory of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is undecidable, but since in $\mathbb{C}[x, e^{\mu x} \mid \mu \in \mathbb{C}]$ there are polynomials we can use it also in that ring, or not? ) @NoahSchweber

Comment: What is $t$? And how do you express "$x(1)=1$"?

Comment: Oh sorry... It should be $$n \in \mathbb{N} \leftrightarrow \exists y \left (n \in \mathbb{C} \land xy'=ny \land y(1)=1\right )$$ I expressed $y(1)=1$ by the formula $\exists z \ : \ (x-1)z=y-1$. @NoahSchweber

Comment: OK, in the expression abbreviated by "$y(1)=1$," what is $x$?

Comment: The variable of the polynomials of $\mathbb{C}[x]$. @NoahSchweber

Comment: @MaryStar You don't have a symbol for that in the language!

Comment: I my last comments I wrote the language wrong. It is $L=\{+, \cdot , \frac{d}{dx}, 0, 1, x\}$. @NoahSchweber

Comment: But, suppose $y$ is $\frac1ee^x$ such that $y(1)=1$. For your formula to work, $\frac{e^{x-1}-1}{x-1}$ needs to be an element of $\mathbb C[x,e^{\mu x}]$ -- how is that the case? [On the other hand, I don't see why they $y(1)=1$ condition is necessary at all, so perhaps the reduction does work].

Comment: (Oh, I see, it's to prevent $y=0$ to work for non-integer $n$).

Comment: So, you mean that the formula doesn't work? @HenningMakholm

Comment: @MaryStar: I'm not sure -- the combination of the two conditions may still have the right effect even though they don't _individually_ do what it says on the tin.

Comment: Ok... I want to show that the positive existential theory of $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , ' , 0 , 1, x\}$ is undecidable. 

Which undecidable positive existential theory can we reduce to the first one? 
@HenningMakholm

Comment: I want to show that the positive existential theory of $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , ' , 0 , 1, x\}$ is undecidable. 

Which undecidable positive existential theory can we reduce to the first one? 
@NoahSchweber

Comment: Are you familiar with quantifier elimination? @NoahSchweber

Comment: Are you familiar with quantifier elimination? @HenningMakholm

Comment: I am, but I don't believe your theory actually admits quantifier elimination - for instance, I can define the set $X=\{e^{\mu x}+e^{2\mu x}: \mu\in\mathbb{C}\}$ using quantifiers, but I don't see a quantifier-free expression for it. For that matter, quantifier elimination is used to show that a theory **is** decidable, which is the opposite of what you want (that said, it's not equivalent to decidability). Let me clarify some previous remarks: I **don't know** how to show that this theory is undecidable; I'm not even sure it **is** undecidable. Why are you confident that it is (or are you)?

Comment: I am looking at an other structure... At the polynomial ring and at the language $\{+, ' , 0, 1\}$. Could you take a look at it? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/224869/existence-of-solution-of-a-differential-equation @NoahSchweber I want to eliminate the quantifier at $\exists y Ly=f \land \psi$.